# How to make notifications appear automatically?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Im new to programming in especially android so please assume I know very little. So I have this app in which the user types in their email, name and their question and sends all this information to a website in which I can see all this information so that i can give an appropriate response. I then send my answer and the user can then see the answer in their application to their question.

Im using android studio and I have to create an activity or something that will generate/ show a notification automatically( without any user interaction) after I answered their question. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Using GCM in android itself only is not enough.You need to implement the code in server side  too.At first the application send android device id to GCM then GCM will return unique id to each device.You need to pass the unique id to server.In server side it sends the message to GCM Unique device id.based on the Unique the device receives message.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Google Cloud Messaging Library for achieving this.

So, when you answer any question, it will send push notification to user on device (like whatsapp) and when user click on that, it will open your answer over there, so user can read it.

Here is library link with sample as well:

https://github.com/google/gcm

Comment: Can you please provide some sample code to support your answer. The links might change in the future, hence making your answer worthless.

Comment: Doesn't gcm require me to type in the notification I want to send everytime, and specify which users i want to send ?. Isn't there a way to make notifications pop up always after a certain activity automatically?